# Listing All Punctuation In A String Using ColdFusion reFindNoCase

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm unable to output a list of all punctuation using reFindNoCase by calling it with the POSIX character class [:punct:] or the actual list of characters it represents, escaped of course shown here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

I expect reFindNoCase to provide a list of positions and locations in the string for each and every presented character in the following example, but that's not the case:

```
    var strRegexString = "!""##$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~";
    var reObjMatchPunctuation = reFindNoCase("([!""##$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~])", LOCAL.strRegexString, 1, True);
    LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation._match = [];
    for (var i=1; i <= arrayLen(LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation.pos); i++){
        if (LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation.pos[i] == 0){
            arrayAppend(LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation._match, "NO MATCH");
        }else if (LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation.len[i] == 0){
            arrayAppend(LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation._match, "ZERO-LENGTH MATCH");
        }else{
            arrayAppend(LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation._match, mid(LOCAL.strRegexString, LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation.pos[i], LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation.len[i]));
        }
    }
    writeDump(LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation);
```

Changing the regex from the above to this also achieves the same results below:

```
var reObjMatchPunctuation = reFindNoCase("([[:punct:]])", LOCAL.strRegexString, 1, True);
```

The result of the above snippet is below which should have 36 matches, but not the case:

[image: Dump of LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation]

Using cfRegex from cfregex.net with the following snippet results in what I was expecting to achieve with reFindNoCase:

```
    var strRegexString = "!""##$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]";
    var reObjMatchPunctuation = new cfc.cfregex.regex("(\p{Punct})");
    WriteDump(LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation.find(LOCAL.strRegexString,1,0,"info"));
```

Which outputs:

<sup><sub>(long image)</sub></sup> [Output of dump from LOCAL.reObjMatchPunctuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZvBG.png)

Which is correct.  Is there something wrong with my syntax?  Is there a known bug with reFind and/or reFindNoCase that this is covered by?

Note:
I used a portion of code snippet from Adam Cameron's blog post to make viewing the results simplified: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/01/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part_10.html

Comment: _"The result of the above snippet is below which should have 36 matches"_ - What makes you say that? refind returns a _single_ match - you would need to loop through increasing the start position to get all 36.

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do here? I've read your comments on Adam's answer, but I don't understand - is this some sort of search fuzziness or spelling thing? Is there a reason you're not using something like Soundex/Metaphone?

Comment: @PeterBoughton Thanks, I wasn't aware of Soundex or Metaphone.  The matching unfortunately isn't conducted on a server I manage so I'm restricted to two choices which are derivatives of the string which imposes spelling strictness or use of regex which allows for mispelling.  I'm open to suggestions as an alternative.

Comment: @PeterBoughton The thanks in Adam's post below is directed to both you and Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at your code more closely. Your assertion is incorrect. `find` functions only find the *first* match of the string / regex in the target string. So your find operation does exactly that: finds the first match in that regex, which is the first character in the string. Your returned array has two elements because you have a subexpression capture in your regex (the `()`), so the first element in the array is the entire match; the second is the subexpression. In this case, the same single character.

To achieve what you want to achieve you need to put your `reFind()` (it doesn't need to be `reFindNoCase()` as you're not looking for alphabetic characters) into a loop, and incrementally advance the starting point of the find operation (ie: the third argument).

Or use `reMatch()`, eg:

```
stringToInspect = "!""##$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~";

regex = "[[:punct:]]";
matches = reMatch(regex, stringToInspect);
writeDump(var=matches, label="Using #regex#");

regex = "[#stringToInspect#]";
matches = reMatch(regex, stringToInspect);
writeDump(var=matches, label="Using #regex#");
```

Note that both examples here have *35* matches... your original test string had `]` duplicated (in the middle just after `\\\`, and again at the end).

Comment: I apologize as I think I had a misunderstanding of what refind and refindnocase returnsubexpressions = true results in.  I see now it only returns the first backreference.  I had been using Python's regular expression library recently which may have something also to do with polluting my mind on what the behaviour of ColdFusion was expected to be.  The ] at the end was something I didn't intend to include in the above example. I'll remove it.  So reMatch() does what I'm looking for to find the matched expression(s), but doesn't provide position information.  Many thanks for correcting me!

Comment: No worries at all. And no need to apologise for anything! Also bear in mind you can use Java regular expressions directly in CFML. I give a precis of this in the three blog articles starting with this one: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/03/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part.html. Dunno if that helps.

Comment: I've been afraid to create Java objects from within ColdFusion for fear of forward version compatibility.  Should I be fearful of that similar to undocumented ColdFusion features or is this something of an exception?  I think matcher() is exactly what I'm looking for which you covered here: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/04/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part.html

Comment: I think your concern is misplaced. One of the whole "things" about CFML is that it runs on Java, and Java can be leveraged accordingly; they don't specifically facilitate in the language for no reason, after all! The Java API will also, I think, be more stable than CF's one ;-)